# How to configure chef inventory, i need to have all information about HD, Processor,Bios,OS,SW

Tags: chef-infra, inventory, inventory-management

configure chef inventory

i need to have all information about HD, Processor,Bios,OS,SW  among all servers

Answer (score 0):

This data is gathered by Ohai and stored back to the Chef Server after each successful run. You can access it via `knife` or any Chef API client library (chef-api, PyChef, jclouds, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm wondering if there is a cookbook for the inventory ?